# Calculate the area of a county bounded by a polygon in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, area

As shown below, for the state of Texas, a portion of Bexar County is bounded by the given Polygon. I want to calculate the area of Bexar County contained within the Polygon.

Here's the code to draw the county outline and the polygon,

```
var states = ee.FeatureCollection('TIGER/2016/States');
var dataset = ee.FeatureCollection('TIGER/2016/Counties');

var tx = states.filter(ee.Filter.eq('STUSPS','TX'));
var bexar = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.eq('COUNTYFP', "029"));

var grid_11527 = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-98.49999937988126,29.499999068288652],
 [-98.43749950919543,29.499999001844174],
 [-98.37499968926618,29.49999902914902],
 [-98.31249975833948,29.499999004224264],
 [-98.24999989063387,29.49999902334256],
 [-98.24999989063387,29.749998494443687],
 [-98.31249975833948,29.749998563183436],
 [-98.37499968926618,29.7499985538551],
 [-98.43749950919543,29.749998545763507],
 [-98.49999937988126,29.74999850903436],
 [-98.49999937988126,29.499999068288652]]]);

dataset = dataset.map(function (f) {
  return f.set('STATEFP', ee.Number.parse(f.get('STATEFP')));
}).filterBounds(tx).filterBounds(bexar);


var countyOutlines = ee.Image().float().paint({
  featureCollection: dataset,
  color: 'black',
  width: 1
});

var txCounties = countyOutlines.clip(tx).clip(bexar);

Map.addLayer(txCounties, {}, 'County Lines', true);
Map.addLayer(dataset, null, 'County Inspector', false);
Map.addLayer(grid_11527, null, 'Grid 11527', true);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the Bexar county area from your dataset. Then you can use the `intersection()` function to get the bounded portion by the polygon and calculate its area in square meters.

```
var bexarC = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.eq('NAME','Bexar')).toList(dataset.size()).get(0)
var intersect_area = ee.Feature(bexarC).intersection(grid_11527).area()
print(intersect_area)
```

Comment: @Ramaraja is there any issues? You removed the answer acceptance.

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake. Thank you for the answer. It works perfectly!